# Need to merge two objects together that each have an array to the matching IDs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two Objects both with arrays "allSessionsParts" and "allSessions".

I am trying to get  allSessions -> SessionsParts to have allSessionsParts only if allSession.ID matchs allSessionsParts.SessionID

[image]

This has been my attempt so far.

```
    const res = allSessions.map(function(sess, i) {
  if (sess.ID === allSessionsParts.SessionID) {
    return {
      sess,
      parts: allSessionsParts
    };
  }
});
```

*UPDATE*

Solution

```
    completeSessions.map(sess => {
    if(sess.SessionParts==null){
        sess.SessionParts=[]
    }
  parts.forEach(part => {
      if(part.SessionID === sess.ID){
          sess.SessionParts.push(part)

      }
  });
})
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: `allSessions.filter(session => allSessionParts.some(sessionPart => session.ID === sessionPart.SessionId)`

Comment: You would make enormous leap forward in the process of getting an answer if put a superhuman effort into that and post your object samples as formatted code, rather than screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the array `allSessions`, for each session you need to iterate over the array `allSessionParts` to check the existance of the matching `SessionId`

```
const validSessions = allSessions.filter(session => 
   allSessionParts.some(sessionPart => session.ID === sessionPart.SessionId
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Iterate over both arrays and compare array1.id === array2.sessionId,` 
`if true push {...object1, ...object2} in new array.` This is the working solution.

```js
var array1 = [
  { id:101, firstName: "rama" },
  { id:102, firstName: "shyam" },
  { id:103, firstName: "jai" }
];

var array2 = [
  { sessionId:101, lastName: "singh" },
  { sessionId:102, lastName: "kumar" },
  { sessionId:105, lastName: "jakhar" }
];

let array3 = [];
array1.forEach(item => {
  array2.forEach(item2 => {
    if(item.id === item2.sessionId){
       array3.push({...item, ...item2})
    }      
  })
})

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need. It is returning an array with 26 objects (the amount of parts) Is their a way on embedding the correct parts in allSessions -> SessionsParts. So three total objects in one array and the correct parts in sessionsparts